# Read Base64 Image from HTML to android picasso adapter

Tags: php, android, mysql, base64

I use PHP with upload64 to upload images which I then store in MYSQL database.

The AJAX part runs fine and image appears.
Now I want to display my picture on Android using the base64 image data `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQ...`

Here is my attempt to read it in Android using **"recycler" view adapter** (using picasso library and Android studio)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject businessObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result");
JSONArray array = businessObject.getJSONArray("data");

Log.d("TAG DATA 123", String.valueOf(array));

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
  String base64Content = jsonObject.getString(o.getString("picture"));
  byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Content, Base64.DEFAULT);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

  ModelsKejadian item = new ModelsKejadian(
    o.getString("judul_laporan"),
    o.getString("id_user_pelapor"),
    o.getString("id_sys_tragedy_child"),
    o.getString("proses"),
    o.getString("datetime"),
    o.getString("ket_tambahan"),
    bitmap
  );
  modelkejadianlist.add(item);
}

adapter = new AdapterKejadian(getActivity(), modelkejadianlist);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But this fails at loading the image.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        ModelsKejadian modelKejadian = modelsKejadianList.get(position);
        holder.nama_profile.setText(modelKejadian.getNama_profile());
        holder.kategori_kejadian.setText(modelKejadian.getKategori_Kejadian());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if(Objects.equals(modelKejadian.getStatus_proses(), "PROSES")){
                holder.status_proses.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d8df3734"));
            }else if(Objects.equals(modelKejadian.getStatus_proses(), "SELESAI")){
                holder.status_proses.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf("#17531e")));
            }
        }
        holder.status_proses.setText(modelKejadian.getStatus_proses());
        holder.waktu.setText(modelKejadian.getWaktu());
        holder.judul_kejadian.setText(modelKejadian.getJudul_kejadian());
        holder.isi_laporan.setText(modelKejadian.getIsi_laporan());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(modelKejadian.getGambar_laporan()).fit().into(holder.gambar_kejadian);

        holder.optionMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item is clicked" +  position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }
```

Comment: `Like This :

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQ...`. That does nothing. Where would you have that string?

Comment: var reader = new FileReader();
                                            reader.readAsDataURL($('.upload_kejadian_laporan')[0].files[0]);
                                            reader.onload = function () {

Comment: ???? I do not you see using that string.

Comment: i Get This Code From JS Ajax in my php Website `var reader = new FileReader();`

Comment: String base64Content = jsonObject.getString(o.getString("picture"));
                                 byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Content, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

i am Load From adapter recycler view

Comment: Where are you talking about? I wanted to know where you had that string. See my first comment. You did not tell anything to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from the string before using `Base64.decode`.

Then in your adapter, `holder.gambar_kejadian.setImageBitmap(modelKejadian.getGambar_laporan());`

Comment: Okay, I should have asked what is failing. Is there an error? Is it just not showing?

Comment: i used piccasso library like this

Picasso.with(mContext).load(`this my bitmap from base64 to android`).fit().into(holder.gambar_kejadian);

in adapter recycler view

if i used base64 to this piccasso code . showing white screen in imageview

Comment: You shouldn't need to use Picasso anyway if you already have the image downloaded. Can you update your RecyclerView Adapter please?

Comment: I just edited my post with additional code adapter
see above